# No login screen after Ubuntu 18.04 update

Tags: 18.04, gdm, tty

After the upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.04.1, when booting instead of going from grub menu to the purple login page, it goes directly to tty1.

The current kernel is 4.15.0-33 and I've already tried to boot with every kernel version from 33 to 29.

Also the `systemctl status gdm3` command gives the active status.

Output of `dmesg --level=err,warn`:

[image: dmesg --level=err,warn]

Output of `lspci -knn | feel -i VGA -A3`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Haswell-ULT 
        Integrated Graphics Controller [1043:16cd]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Add the output of  `dmesg --level=err,warn`  to your post.

Comment: Done, I don't know why the Imgur quality I so low tough.

Comment: Add the output of  `lspci -knn | grep -i vga -A3`, post  as plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, eliminate a possible disk file system problem...**

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Next, eliminate a possible video subsystem problem...**

At the GRUB menu, hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key, and edit the line that contains "splash quiet" to "splash quiet nomodeset", hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> to continue booting. See if it will fully boot, even if the video display isn't at the correct resolution. If it boots, do one of the following...

**1. Eliminate a possible wayland problem...**

Boot to recovery mode, and choose root access. Then type:

```
sudo mount -o rw,remount /
```

In `terminal`...

- `cd /etc/gdm3` # change directory
- `sudo pico custom.conf` # edit this file

Find and change:

`#WaylandEnable=false`

To this:

`WaylandEnable=false`

Save the file.

- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` # select gdm3 DM

Select gdm3 and OK.

- `reboot` # reboot the computer

**2. Update/reinstall the current nouveau/Nvidia video drivers.**

**Update #1:**

While trying the wayland fix, errors indicated a gdm3 problem. Reinstalling gdm3 resolved the problem.

Comment: fsck gives no errors, splash quiet is "quiet splash" in my file so I wrote "quiet splash nomodeset" and after ctrl+x the result is always the tty

Comment: @Questioner what about the wayland fix and the video drivers?

Comment: While doing the Wayland part, doing "sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3" gives: "gdm3 is ruined or not completely installed".

Edit:

That message made me think and so doing this steps I've solved the problem!

1- reedit custom.conf leaving #WaylandEnable=false

2- rebooted in normal mode

3- from tty1: sudo apt install gdm3


That's it, maybe the update broke gdm3

Comment: @Questioner ah, there's your problem. Do "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get install gdm3" and "reboot". Please see the update to my answer, and accept it if it was helpful.

Comment: Yes, already said in the edit

Answer (score 0):

If someone have the same problem and is using a virtual machine, which was my case. Here's what I've done.
Change the graphics controller to VBoxVGA.
I found that there: [Black screen in Ubuntu in Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126956/black-screen-in-ubuntu-in-virtual-box?rq=1) and it solved my issue.

Comment: Welcome to AU.  It is recommended practice here to at least summarize the contents of the link you refer to.  this way, your answer remains valid even if the link is broken or its content is modified.