# Problem Booting up ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04

Whenever I try to boot up Ubuntu, it shows a purple screen, then  black screen, the the Ubuntu start up screen but when it reaches here, the screen will load 4 dots out of 5 and then the screen will freeze. please help.

Comment: What brand/model system? And what video card/chip? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Please see my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068809/no-login-screen-after-ubuntu-18-04-1-update/1068847#1068847. Please remember to vote for it if it was helpful. Thanks!