# Login screen throws back to login screen

Tags: gnome, xorg, login

Yesterday I updated by Ubuntu 18.04 and now whenever I try to login via GUI it throws me back to login screen.

I have done the following things
1.Using Ctr+alt+F1 I have done the login using terminal and the user gets logged in
2.Removed ./Xauthority
3.Changed the permission of ./Xauthority to 777 for the user.

So is there anything else that I should try?

Comment: try to change desktop manager. In my case, change from gdm to lightdm worked.

Comment: I am using lightdm.

Comment: See [Ubuntu 18.04 Login window loop](https://askubuntu.com/a/1086383/902634).

Comment: Actually I reinstalled lightdm and it fixed my issue.